# The differentiability of a function follows from the differentiability of its composition with others?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\varphi:U \to V$, where $U$ and $V$ are open subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ and $\mathbb R^m$ respectively. Suppose that for every differentiable function  $f: V \to \mathbb R$ function $f \circ \varphi$ is differentiable. Does it mean that $\varphi$ is differentiable?

Comment: Just let $f(x_1,\dots , x_m)= x_1$ to see the first component of $\varphi$ is differentiable. Lather rinse repeat.

Comment: @zhw. The problem is that the differentaibility of a function doesn't follow from the existence of all partial derivatives

Comment: While that is true, it has nothing to do with what I wrote.